# About DOM elements internal indentifier

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'd like to identify univocally some DOM elements (specifically, the `<li>` elements of an `<ul>` list). First, I thought about using the `id` or `data-` attributes, but I declined the option because these attributes can be changed easily using the developer tools.

Is there any internal id that I could use for this purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is no. You can store references to elements in variables, but there is no internal id.

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you mean you want to get a collection of all `<li>` in a page?

Comment: The best option would likely be `document.querySelectorAll`. With that you get a node list, e.g. `querySelectorAll('ul li')` will give all `li`, and item 1 will always be item 1 (in markup), no matter class or id.

Comment: @zero298, what I mean is if there's an internal id that could be used to identify uniquely some elements of my page and that cannot be changed, as the normal attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't expose a hash code-like property with which to identify objects.

If you want to hold references to specific children of a specific `ul` element that you know will always be at a specific location in the page, select them directly using `document.querySelectorAll()` with as many child combinators and `:nth-child()` selectors as necessary. Most browser developer tools will allow you to copy a unique selector for your desired `ul` element using the element inspector based on the location of that element in your DOM structure. Just add `> li` to that selector and loop through the child element nodes as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

There is no internal ids for elements. There is no way to really set an id on an element that can not be changed.

Only thing you really can do is hold references to elements in an array/object/variables, but even a person could set a break point in the code and alter that.

So in the end, there is really no way to identify an element and not have a person muck in developer tools and change it.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to identify DOM elements is to use either class property or id:

```
document.getElementById(id)
document.getElementsByClassName(className)
```

Here is also an option to iterate over elements found by tag:

```
document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)
```

If you don't have any control over HTML markup I believe there are no difference in your case.

Comment: OP is asking how to know that element 1 is element 1 without  someone altering the id of that element.... Doubt this actually answers OPs question.